# Why does the observable return before callback completes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, mqtt

Component A subscribes to an observable in Service B:

Component A:

```
testMqtt(){
    console.log('testMqtt is called');
    this.serviceB.connectToBroker().subscribe({
      next: (resp) => console.log('response from connection to mqtt: ', resp.connected),
      error: (err) => console.log('error from connection to mqtt: ', err)
    });
  }
```

Service B:

```
  connectToBroker(){
    let client = mqtt.connect(this.url, {clientId: 'abc123'});
    return of(client.on('connect', (packet) => {
      console.log('testing value of connected: ', JSON.stringify(packet));
      console.log('value of client connected: ', client.connected);
    }))
  };
```

The idea is to reflect the value of 'client.connected' (Service B) in 'resp.connected' (Component A). Why does console.log from testMqtt() always show the value of resp.connected as **false** when the value of client.connected inside connectToBroker() in Service B is **true**? Which rxjs operator can I use in Service B that will allow the **client.on** callback to complete before returning a response to the subscription in Component A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of the service is using a callback, so the code inside the function will execute and I dont think, the value will get emitted, after the callback is run, could you try using [`fromEvent`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent) to create an observable listener instead!

```
connectToBroker(){
    let client = mqtt.connect(this.url, {clientId: 'abc123'});
    return fromEvent(client, 'connect').pipe(
        tap(() => {
            console.log('testing value of connected: ', JSON.stringify(packet));
            console.log('value of client connected: ', client.connected);
        }),
    );
  };
```

Comment: fromEvent works well!

Answer (score 0):

As [@Naren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5924562/naren-murali) mentioned in his answer, `of` operator is used to convert a set of arguments into an observable which is useful to emit the set of values in sequence. However, it doesn't handle asynchronous operations like the callback.

To get rid from this issue and handle asynchronous operations, you can use the `new Observable(() => {...})` constructor. You have to make sure that the observable only completes after the callback is executed.

Try this **:**

```
connectToBroker() {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      let client = mqtt.connect(this.url, {clientId: 'abc123'});
      client.on('connect', (packet) => {
        console.log('testing value of connected: ', JSON.stringify(packet));
        console.log('value of client connected: ', client.connected);
        observer.next({ connected: client.connected });
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Existing rxjs fromEvent obviates the need for a new Observable, but good to know that approach is also feasible.